# How to collect host syslog from with in a docker container

Tags: containers, syslog

How do I collect host's `syslog` from with in a docker container running in the same host?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to mount the host's log directory into the container that runs your log collector of choice. E.g:

`docker run -d -v /var/log/:/path/in/container/ logstash <logstash options ...>`

Note that you should be mounting the **directory** as opposed to the logfile itself. If you bind-mount the file, collection will cease after each log rotation, until you restart the container.